# Ethernet interface name not consistent

Tags: networking, systemd, network-interface, yocto, systemd-networkd

I am seeing this peculiar behavior after boot, i see the interfaces as enp2s0, enp1s0 and when i remove the module and load it again, i see eth0, eth1. I need to get back enp2s0, enp1s0 as my scripts depends on the name. Can you please help me to change the interface name

After boot:

```
root@panther2:~# lsmod | grep r8169
r8169                  81920  0
root@panther2:~# ifconfig 
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:E1:A1:3F:21:3F  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:E1:A1:3F:F8:17  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3ee1:a1ff:fe3f:f817/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21142 (20.6 KiB)  TX bytes:24150 (23.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4692 (4.5 KiB)  TX bytes:4692 (4.5 KiB)
```

Module removed/loaded: rmmod r8169 ; modprobe r8169

```
root@panther2:~# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:E1:A1:3F:21:3F  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:E1:A1:3F:F8:17  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3ee1:a1ff:fe3f:f817/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15675 (15.3 KiB)  TX bytes:13552 (13.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7344 (7.1 KiB)  TX bytes:7344 (7.1 KiB)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ip link set eth0 down
ip link set eth0 name enp1s0
ip link set enp1s0 up

ip link set eth1 down
ip link set eth1 name enp2s0
ip link set enp2s0 up
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  why should this be done manually. Why udevd doesn't change the name?